# Unable to upgrade zfsutils-linux on 20.04

Tags: apt, system-installation, upgrade, dpkg, zfs

So. I'm stuck.  This is recent installation of Ubuntu 20.04.  All disks are setup as ZFS filesystems.

```
 ⚡ root@docker /var zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
bpool  1,88G   506M  1,38G        -         -     0%    26%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
data   10,9T  1,76G  10,9T        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
rpool   920G  7,61G   912G        -         -     0%     0%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

bpool is my boot partion, rpool my root.  It looks like this:

```
 ⚡ root@docker /var zfs list
NAME                                                                                                     USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                                                                                    505M  1,26G       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                                                                               503M  1,26G       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_u1x577                                                                                 503M  1,26G      269M  /boot
data                                                                                                    1,76G  10,5T       96K  /data
data/home                                                                                                110M  10,5T      110M  /home
data/var                                                                                                1,65G  10,5T     1,58G  /var
data/var/lib                                                                                            77,8M  10,5T       96K  /var/lib
data/var/lib/docker                                                                                     77,7M  10,5T      772K  /var/lib/docker
data/var/lib/docker/3507eb58f488f64c7b9fc52fec17371e733dccf691d88a55ce23e4a732694f1d                      84K  10,5T     76,5M  legacy
data/var/lib/docker/66f1d3eb20e22d69da12e47e6e363c2c4ccfe71d9c9d58b46c4a27a0a143b354                    5,02M  10,5T     11,1M  legacy
data/var/lib/docker/7fac28892c840428c90e8a0eff4289b3791f816ea8eef6a0606d141fb2f83ada                    65,5M  10,5T     76,5M  legacy
data/var/lib/docker/cd2984a7ec9b4a4d4138d92c189d5c4c13fe4ace09aa88f3cd7603fd65005042                    6,31M  10,5T     6,30M  legacy
data/volumes                                                                                             308K  10,5T      308K  /data/volumes
rpool                                                                                                   7,61G   884G       96K  /
rpool/ROOT                                                                                              7,48G   884G       96K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_u1x577                                                                                7,48G   884G     3,31G  /
```

I've snipped off the rest, because I don't think it's important.  If I run `apt install` I get the following:

```
 ⚡ root@docker /var apt install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
INFO Requesting to save current system state
Successfully saved as "autozsys_apdldl"
Setting up zfsutils-linux (0.8.3-1ubuntu12) ...
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
zfs-import-scan.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for zfs-mount.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process.
See "systemctl status zfs-mount.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript zfs-mount, action "start" failed.
● zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: signal) since Fri 2020-04-24 23:51:39 CEST; 9ms ago
       Docs: man:zfs(8)
    Process: 71542 ExecStart=/sbin/zfs mount -a (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
   Main PID: 71542 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)

Apr 24 23:51:38 docker systemd[1]: Starting Mount ZFS filesystems...
Apr 24 23:51:38 docker zfs[71542]: cannot mount '/var': directory is not empty
Apr 24 23:51:38 docker zfs[71542]: cannot mount '/home': mount failed
Apr 24 23:51:39 docker systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=11/SEGV
Apr 24 23:51:39 docker systemd[1]: zfs-mount.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 24 23:51:39 docker systemd[1]: Failed to start Mount ZFS filesystems.
dpkg: error processing package zfsutils-linux (--configure):
 installed zfsutils-linux package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-initramfs:
 zfs-initramfs depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-initramfs (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zfs-zed:
 zfs-zed depends on zfsutils-linux (>= 0.8.3-1ubuntu12); however:
  Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package zfs-zed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 zfsutils-linux
 zfs-initramfs
 zfs-zed
INFO Updating GRUB menu
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, it looks like `zfsutils-linux` is trying to remount /var and /home, but it can't because the directory isn't empty (because I'm assuming it's already mounted?).

Does anybody have any ideas where I can troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what is going on.

I have `/var` and `/home` as part of the `data` ZFS pool.  Apparently at some point when it wasn't mounted, something wrote in `/var` and `/home` which means the `data` ZFS pool can't mount because as the message says `cannot mount '/var': directory is not empty`.

This would have been a little clearer if they had included the pool name in the error message.

If anybody else gets into this situation:

1. You need to stop all the services on the box that could be writing
   to the directories affected.
2. Then you need to move the directories out of the way.  `mv /var 
   /var.old`
3. Now force zfs to mount the directories: `zfs mount -a`
4. For each directory affected, copy the old files over the new `rsync 
   -avz --delete /var.old/* /var/`
5. Cross your fingers (press your thumbs, or whatever culturally 
   appropriate gesture fits)
6. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (in my case, a few files existed in `/home` which prevented `/home/username` from a clean mount), but solved it differently and with less hassle:

1. Boot into recovery mode from GRUB and select *Drop to root shell prompt*
2. unmount all ZFS datasets: `zfs unmount -a`
3. verify that all pools have been unmounted
4. manually mount the problematic datasets: `zfs mount pool/home`
5. check for files that shouldn't be there and move those out of the way:

   `mv /home/username /home/username.old`
6. check whether mounting all ZFS datasets still produces errors

   `zfs mount -a`
7. if so, repeat, otherwise `reboot`
8. find out what to do with the files in `/home/username.old`

Answer (score 0):

I did an upgrade for my Ubuntu 20.04, and similar errors occured like this:

```
Package zfsutils-linux is not configured yet.
```

I searched and find these commands for package not configured problem

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/ /var/lib/dpkg/info_old/
$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info/
$ sudo apt-get update

$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/* /var/lib/dpkg/info_old/
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info
$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info_old/ /var/lib/dpkg/info/
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Please explain in your post.